# Date format to show month as text

Tags: powershell, datetime-format

Struggling with this one.   I'm trying to get the below to display like this: 19 Nov 2014

I suppose the real issue here is that I can't find any documentation to get the month to be displayed as text because if I could even get "19 November 2014" then I would just truncate it.

```
$prevWD = (date)+"$(-1+$(@(1,2-eq7-(date).dayofweek)))"
$prevWD.ToString("dd MM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$date = Get-Date -Format "dd MMM yy"
```

See MS Documentation: [Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692801.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this:

```
[datetime]::now.toString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Or if you want yesterday:

```
[datetime]::now.addDays(-1).toString("dd MMM yyyy")
```

Comment: Didn't know it would be that simple!  I've only just now seen that option on TechNet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$dt = "{0:d MMM yyyy}" -f (get-date)
write-host $dt
```